# either crystal reports registry key permissions are insufficient in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I really find it difficult to solve this problem.

I am using a crystal report in VB.NET 2008 and if I loaded and run the crystal report in a form, I got this error - "either crystal reports registry key permissions are insufficient in vb.net " . I am using my WINDOWS 7 OS. If I transfer to other PC with XP OS, there is no error occurs.

Does anybody know this? Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you compile the application in x86, x64 or ANY CPU? See if it works to compile it as x86 only. Same goes with any installer you're creating.

I remember having an issue with x64 systems and our installer a few years back. The installer only installed the x64 version of the CR files on the client machines and there for the application failed.

Comment: Yes, I compiled it in other CPU.. It works well in other CPU but not on my PC. I am using x64. How to make it work in x64? Will you help me? thanks

Comment: If you try to manually install the x64 and x32 runtimes on your machine, will it work?